# package electron atom angularJS error on build

Tags: angularjs, electron

I develop an app on atom electron, I use angularJS as Framework for routing URLs

If I run

```
electron main.js
```

all is ok but if I want to package my app with electron-packager

```
electron-packager ./ appName --out=release --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --version=0.36.0 --overwrite=true --ignore=\"release\
```

I have an error in angularjs

```
Erreur de lecture du fichier <ng-view class="ng-scope" data-ng-animate="1">
```

all files are loaded like when I dev... but angularJS crash....

My `package.json` has the `dependencies` like this:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "angular": ">=1.4.8",
    "angular-animate": ">=1.4.8",
    "angular-aria": ">=1.4.8",
    "angular-material": ">=1.0.0",
    "angular-route": ">=1.4.8",
    "angular-sanitize": ">=1.4.8",
    "angular-translate": ">=2.8.1",
    "electron-debug": ">=0.5.1",
    "electron-prebuilt": ">=0.35.4",
    "ovh": ">=1.1.3",
    "walk": ">=2.3.9",
    "winston": ">=2.1.1"
 },
```

Comment: Have you added AngularJS as a dependency in the `package.json`? You can list it here so we can check, maybe.

Comment: this is my dependancies:  "dependencies": {
    "angular": ">=1.4.8",
    "angular-animate": ">=1.4.8",
    "angular-aria": ">=1.4.8",
    "angular-material": ">=1.0.0",
    "angular-route": ">=1.4.8",
    "angular-sanitize": ">=1.4.8",
    "angular-translate": ">=2.8.1",
    "electron-debug": ">=0.5.1",
    "electron-prebuilt": ">=0.35.4",
    "ovh": ">=1.1.3",
    "walk": ">=2.3.9",
    "winston": ">=2.1.1"
  },

Comment: I think you should edit your question and add the whole console log it gives you while building with `electron-packager`. My best bet is that that error actually exists in your project, but maybe it's not loaded when running with `electron` - maybe `electron-packager` reads every file to compress/obfuscate/uglify it, and that's why it detects the error.

Comment: sorry, I can build the app, create an asar, put in into electron ressources but whent I start the app, there are problems on angular and one error in console: "Error reading file <ng-view class="ng-scope">"

Comment: Ok, I have found the problem, so, I put my app.asar in electron/resources     and if i lunch a console and go to electron folder and execute electron.exe, it work fine, BUT if I double click on electron.exe I have an error.....why?????